# jQuery multi function initiate?

Tags: jquery, function

Ok, the title is a little vague so my apologies but I'm trying to get the correct syntax if any to start a certain segment of jQuery code based on an OR logic. For example:

```
$("#button").click OR $("#button2").click
{

//do this code....



}
```

Anyone have the correct syntax for this? Or perhaps a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#button, #button2").click(function () {
    // do this
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select both elements:

```
$("#button, #button2").click(function() { ... });
```

In the handler, you can use the `this` keyword to find out which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button #button2").click {    
    function() {
        doSomething();
        doSomethingElse()   
    }     
}
```

This is called an **anonymous** function. It runs in the scope of the click event. You need it to wrap up your code so that it runs during the event, rather than when the click event is registered.

Comment: Your trigger finger is horrifigly too fast. :)

Answer (score 0):

i believe what you're looking for would be

```
$("#button,#button2").click(function(){...});
```

edit: seems like i wasn't the only one with the answer:)